# Installation of JDBC driver to access Mariadb database from Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, jdbc, mariadb, macos-high-sierra

I have a Mariadb database running on a Synology NAS which I want to access from Matlab installed on a Mac.

Here are the steps I have followed:

1. downloaded the MariaDB Connector/J 2.3.0 mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar
2. created a folder MyDrivers in the /Library folder and moved the driver there
3. added the above folder to the PATH variable
4. added the full path of the driver to the CLASSPATH variable
5. as per Matlab's tutorial, created a javaclasspath.txt file which is saved in the Matlab prefdir folder (`/Users/cedric/Library/Application Support/MathWorks/MATLAB/R2018a/javaclasspath.txt`). The content of the javaclasspath.txt file is `/Library/MyDrivers/mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar`

When I try to configure the data source in Matlab, I get an error message "Unable to find jdbc driver on Matlab Java class path". I believe points 3, 4 and 5 are properly done (cf outputs below).

So my questions are around the copy / paste of the .jar file of the driver. Is there anything I need to do on top of placing it in a relevant folder?

I've tried to execute it with `java -jar /Library/MyDrivers/mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar`in the Terminal. This provides: `no main manifest attribute, in /Library/MyDrivers/mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar`

Thinking it might not be an executable jar, I've tried `java -cp /Library/MyDrivers/mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver;`

This returns

```
Error: Main method not found in class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend     javafx.application.Application`
```

Any hints as to what to do exactly? I'm running out of tips from the researches I have done so far...

### Output of env in the Terminal

```
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/48/d95l77ys4hv4xbfgtsh0rh1w0000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.l8pI2zNcXw/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=404
OLDPWD=/Users/cedric/.Trash/mariadb-java-client-2.2.6-sources 23.44.30/org/mariadb
TERM_SESSION_ID=396C6E65-006B-4BAF-B137-A270A36E397F
USER=cedric
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.QZhGI9ZjXf/Listeners
PATH=/Library/MyDrivers/mysql-connector-java-8.0.12/mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar:/Library/MyDrivers:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/cedric
LOGNAME=cedric
CLASSPATH=.:/Library/MyDrivers/mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar:
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a8
_=/usr/bin/env
```

### Output of javaclasspath('all') in Matlab

The last file that Matlab returns is the one of the driver: `/Library/MyDrivers/mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar`

### System Specs:

Mac OS HighSierra 10.13.4

Matlab R2018a

```
Java -version: 
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

Driver Jdbc MariaDB Connector/J 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Your attempts to run the mariadb jar show that it is fine. java is (correctly) telling you that this jar (nor the Driver class) can be treated as an application entrypoint.

Adding the lib to PATH does nothing.

adding the lib to CLASSPATH isn't recommended but can help; the only thing it does is define the classpath a java VM will use if no explicit classpath is provided. Matlab, like just about every complex java app, definitely has its own classpath. I'm not personally familiar with how matlab does things, but I'd give it 99% odds that matlab therefore completely ignores the CLASSPATH variable too.

That leaves this `classpath.txt` file which seems to be ignored. I don't think that's the way to configure classpath in matlab. The documentation over at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaclasspath.html should help you out. At the very least you can ask matlab about what it thinks the classpath is.

Comment: Good to read that things are in place on the java and driver side.

Comment: Good to read that things are in place on the java and driver side.

As for the Matlab side, name of the file is actually javaclasspath.txt as per this page: [link] https://ch.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/mysql-jdbc-mac.html#bt8lx7a-3

When running the javaclasspath function (`javaclasspath('all')`), it lists this directory among others: `/Library/MyDrivers/mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar` ; which is the one in which the driver is.

So things seems to be running fine on that end as well. I am definitely missing something here, but still don't know what precisely :-/

Answer (score 0):

The hardest issue to solve is the non-existing one...
Thanks to rzwitserloot who confirmed the driver was well installed, i decided to go step by step. First set up a tiny java programme to test the driver which proved fine indeed, after adjustment of couple of database connection settings (port and ip). Then, despite the MATLAB message of driver not to be found, i did the same with matlab (coding instead of using the interface). This worked fine as well actually.
After that, I did try to connect via the database interface, despite the "unable to find driver" message. Connection succeeded, and the "unable to find driver" message disappeared.